# Get Value of Cell Row in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to get the value of a two `columns`, If one column is `blank` it still returns a value for example if the  `column1` is `blank` and  `column2` is not it will still return a value.
My Code:

```
DateTime rowtype = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["CreatedOn"].Value);
  string status= row.Cells["Status"].Value.ToString();
         if (rowtype < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) &&  status == "Open")
            {
               row.HeaderCell.Value = ">7";
            }
```

How can i change the HeaderCell, only if the two columns contain the correct values?

Comment: No, `Status must equal Open and CreatedOn must equals 7 days ago` for `row.HeaderCell.Value` to be `>7`

Comment: `CreatedOn must equals 7 days ago`?? Or `CreatedOn must earlier than 7 days ago`?

Comment: `CreatedOn must equals 7 days ago`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment:

```
DateTime rowtype = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["CreatedOn"].Value);
string status= row.Cells["Status"].Value.ToString();
DateTime dt = new DateTime(rowtype.Year, rowtype.Month, rowtype.Day);
DateTime today = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
if (dt == today.AddDays(-7)  &&  status == "Open")
{
    row.HeaderCell.Value = ">7";
}
```